# where do module.exports export your function and what is the use of it when we still use require to import the code into your module

Tags: javascript, node.js

i Have written the following code in node.js

notes.js

```
console.log('notes app is running');
```

app.js

```
const notes = require('./notes.js');

console.log(notes);
```

When i import the code and run  app.js output  is  shown as `notes app is running`

Now i updated the code  for notes.js

```
console.log('notes app is running');
addNote = () =>{
 console.log('addNote');
 return  'New note';
} ;
```

Now i want to use the following  arrow function in my code so updtaed my

app.js

```
const notes = require('./notes.js');
     var res = notes.addNote();
    console.log(res);
    console.log(notes);
```

Now it is Throwing me  error

```
notes.addNote is not a function
```

1) I know i should use module.exports.addNote

2) But i want to know why we can see a log which we have written in notes.js without using module.exports statment. why can't we use require statment and store total code and call the function from that varable  as we do for a instance of a class

3)More preciously where do module.export export your code (i mean to which directrey )

4)Plese  correct me if anything is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(#1 and #4 don't need answers, so I've left them off.)

> 2) But i want to know why we can see a log which we have written in notes.js without using module.exports statment.

With Node.js's style of modules (which is a flavor of CommonJS), a module is loaded and executed when it's first `require`d. Your `console.log` is in the module's code, so when you `require` it (the first time), that code gets run.

> why can't we use require statment and store total code and call the function from that varable as we do for a instance of a class

You can, if that's what you want to do:

```
exports = {
    // code here as object properties
    addNote: () => {
        console.log('addNote');
        return  'New note';
    }
};
```

and

```
const mod = require("./notes.js");
mode.addNote();
```

> 3)More preciously where do module.export export your code (i mean to which directrey )

To the [*module cache*](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, node caches all modules. In order to do this, it starts at the entry point file (e.g. you app.js file) and recursively searches all **require** statements (or imports).

As node parses modules, any code at the top level of the file will execute - such as your console.log line

```
console.log('notes app is running');
```

However, note, that at this point nothing in the file has been exposed to any other part of your codebase. Instead, node takes any value that is exported via module.exports and adds it to an internal cache. This cache is keyed on the path to the file as appeared in the require statements (converted to an absolute path), so for example, the following require statements:

```
const module1 = require('../module1.js');
const module2 = require('../module2.js');
```

will result in cache entries which look like:

```
<path_to>/../module1.js = ... contents of module1.exports
<path_to>/../module2.js = ... contents of module2.exports
```

Any time you require one of those modules again, you will get the cached version of the modules, it will NOT re-parse the file. For your example, it means that not matter how many times you require the notes.js file, it will only print your console.log('notes app is running'); statement once.

Because of the way node loads modules in isolation, you can ONLY access the elements which are exported via module.exports. Which means any function you define in the file but do not export cannot be accessed.

So, to directly address your questions:

- I know i should use module.exports.addNote

  - Yes. Though, not you can also assign a new object to module.exports, e.g module.exports = { addNote };
- But i want to know why we can see a log which we have written in notes.js without using module.exports statment. why can't we use require statment and store total code and call the function from that varable as we do for a instance of a class

  - Because node parses all required files while generating it's cache
- More preciously where do module.export export your code (i mean to which directrey )

  - They're not stored in a directory, but rather cached in memory based on the file name and contents of module.exports
- Plese correct me if anything is wrong

  - guess this one doesn't need an answer